# Use editable QComboBox to select value from list or get manual input

Tags: c++, qt4, qcombobox

I am trying to use a QComboBox to allow a user to either manually input an IP address or select a server from a list of values. I have the QComboBox set to be editable and by default has an empty list. There is a scan function that finds servers on the network and adds entries to the QComboBox list. The list shows the server's name while the IP address is stored in the data for that entry.

I am attempting to use the currentIndex() function to determine if it is a manual IP address (if currentIndex() == -1) or which entry is selected.

If I input an IP address manually before scanning (so the QComboBox list is empty) that works. currentIndex() is -1 and it parses the IP from the QComboBox text. However, once I scan and add to the list, currentIndex() seems only to return a list index (0+). Also, when the items are added to the QComboBox list, the first item (index 0) is selected automatically.

Any ideas about what I need to do to make this work the way I want? Do I need a "blank" list entry to serve as a placeholder for manual input (either an empty string or maybe "enter IP address" prompt)? Do I need to watch for typing in the QComboBox and set it to index -1 (or something)? Do I need to use something besides index to determine if there was manual entry?

I have a regex to restrict input into the QComboBox to look like an IP address. This seems to work, though, once list entries are added, I can type letters to begin with. It seems to be trying to auto-complete with the list entries (which don't follow the regex since I have the name displayed). I think I'm okay with this behavior since once I type a number it sticks to the IP format. I do not want to be able to edit the list entries. I would be okay with adding manual entries by IP address into the list once a connection is made (like a history mode), but that is not necessary.

Comment: I can't test it currently but.. what about comparing currentText() with itemText(currentIndex()) ? If it's different it means that text has been entered..

Answer (score 1):

I think, your scan provides all possible servers to your datamodel. In this case you don't need to add  userinput to your data but only selection of an existing item.
To allow input of a known ip you should add an empty string as first item. Then you can use either signal editTextChanged or eventFilter to check the input and select a server. I tried it in python3, pyqt5, qt5, for this attempt i stored some servers in a dictionary. In both cases the correct server was selected after input of an existing ip:

first my values in the list:

```
    self.combo.setInsertPolicy(0)        # if no input necessary
    self.item_dict = {
                                '123.456.7.890':'server1',
                                '234.567.8.901':'server2',
                                '345.678.9.012':'server3',
                                '456.789.0.123':'server4'
                               } 
    self.comboSetItems()

def comboSetItems(self):
    self.combo.addItem('')    # this item should be edited
    for val in self.item_dict:
        self.combo.addItem(self.item_dict[val])
```

using signal:

```
    self.combo.editTextChanged.connect(self.itemEdited)

def itemEdited(self,string):
    # every input sends the signal :-(
    if string in self.item_dict:
        for i in range(0,self.combo.count()):
            if self.item_dict[string] == self.combo.itemText(i):
                self.combo.clearEditText()
                self.combo.setCurrentIndex(i)
            else:
                pass
```

using eventFilter:

```
    self.combo.installEventFilter(self)

def eventFilter(self,obj,event):
        if obj == self.combo: 
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter):
                if self.combo.currentText() in self.item_dict:
                    for i in range(0,self.combo.count()):
                        if self.combo.itemText(i) == self.item_dict[self.combo.currentText()]:
                            self.combo.clearEditText()
                            self.combo.setCurrentIndex(i)
                        else:
                            pass
                return True
```